Why is a banking website not loading outside of China?
I've been trying to log onto the Agricultural Bank of China's personal banking website for the past month to no avail. The URL is https://perbank.abchina.com/EbankSite/startup.do. When you visit this link it automatically adds a ?r=nnnn random session or token to the URL, where nnnn is a 16 character HEX string by the looks of it.
I physically travel in and out of China's "Great Firewall" (GFW) often (i.e. into and out of mainland China). When I'm within the GFW borders, the personal banking website loads pretty much instantaneously, as you would expect for any banking website. However, when I'm outside the GFW, the site loads for several minutes and often just timeouts or errors.
I've tried contacting the bank's customer technical support but they only gave me generic guidelines on using the latest Microsoft Edge browser. They said that the site should be accessible from anywhere in the world. And it was actually indeed accessible from outside the GFW up to about a month ago.
Any ideas as to what the problem may be, and is it possible to identify any specific blocks or errors from the browser's network console?

How for away from China are you? Are you on a reliable internet connection? Here in Germany, the site loads reasonable fast (a few seconds) and 100% reliably.

This site is accessible from Texas, USA. Tested from Firefox and Edge browsers, Windows 11 version 24H2.
If you are on Edge, try loading the website in a "InPrivate" Window (CTRL+SHIFT+N). Also known as "Incognito" on Chrome, and simply "Private Window" on Firefox. If this works, it suggests your browser settings/cookies/cache may need to be reset.
If that doesn't work, try accessing the website while connected to a VPN, to bypass any restrictions your Internet Provider may be implementing (or subjected to by China).
